# Cant get lm-sensors to load ATI Radeon temp and fan or output all settings

Tags: ati, fglrx, lm-sensors

New to Linux and having minor issues :/ . I followed [this guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2780) initially but did not recieve the proper output and did not show my ATI Radeon HD 5000 temp or fan speed. Then used [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto), same problems exhibited. No 
issues installing  and no errors. I think its not reading i2c for some reason. The proprietary driver is installed and functioning correctly according fglrxinfo. I can use aticonfig commands and view both temp and fan. After scouring the interwebs for two weeks I am still left with no solutions that I have found or how to properly get it working.

Any ideas on how to get the ATI Radeon sensors working under 'sensors'?

When i run 'sudo sensors-detect' this is my ouput

```
# sensors-detect revision 5984 (2011-07-10 21:22:53 +0200)
# System: LENOVO IdeaPad Y560 (laptop)
# Board: Lenovo KL3

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): y
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): y
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x8502
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): y
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): y
Using driver `i2c-i801' for device 0000:00:1f.3: Intel 3400/5 Series (PCH)

Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)
```

My output for 'sensors' is:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +58.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +56.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +57.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:       +58.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:       +57.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

and my '/etc/modules' is:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

lp
rtc

# Generated by sensors-detect on Fri Nov 30 23:24:31 2012
# Chip drivers
coretemp
```

Update: I am still experiencing this issue. I have done a fresh OS install, as well as trying all of the possible ways of installing fglrx through the unofficial wiki. Any ideas of Help is more than appreciated.

Comment: i got same problem as you. have you got a solution after all those years sir?

Answer (score 1):

why not using aticonfig tools to get the current GPU temperature?

`aticonfig --adapter=all --odgt`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the ISA adapter temperatures **are** your ATI Radeon temperatures. I say this because sometimes, if the driver doesn't provide a name for an extension (ISA, PCI, PCIe, etc.), the system may automatically call it by the ISA bus number.